# Type conversion performance

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

both conversion does take same time for execution or different?How casting is done by .net

```
float j = r;
decimal e = Convert.ToDecimal(j);in convert class using todecimal method is converting to decimal
decimal tt=(decimal)j;// How does this work in casting (Exactly How boxing and unboxing works)
```

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself?

Comment: Default answer:  _"If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses."_ http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: i seen the only difference in syntax@SonerGönül

Comment: If you decomile `Convert.ToDecimal(float value)` the source is `return (decimal)value;`

Comment: I sorry but for me this questions are stupid -1 !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference because [`System.Convert.ToDecimal(Single)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he38a8ca(v=vs.110).aspx) uses exactly the same code as you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs).

```
public static decimal ToDecimal(float value) {
    return (decimal)value;
}
```

But in general you should measure it yourself first. Here is what [E. Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) would say:

*"If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses."*

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the call stack for them both you would see.

```
decimal tt=(decimal)j;
```

has 1 less function call than.

```
decimal e = Convert.ToDecimal(j);
```

Because of the reason the person before me put in there answer (I would have put this in a comment but I do not have 50 rep so I can't).

so very marginally

```
decimal tt=(decimal)j;
```

Is faster.

Comment: This is micro-optimization at it's "best", you will seldom, if ever, notice a significant difference.  
Here's a little check which proves it: http://ideone.com/yzJyAf